# I have a priority 1-5 and turnaround time ranging from 6 to 96 hours

Tags: xpages

I have a list of numbered priorities that match required turn around times e.g. 1= 6 hours; 2=12 hours

Once a document takes more than then the indicated turnaround time to complete, I need a visual indicator like change color to red or green to alert people. This is an XPages application.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a site to teach programming. You can't just state what you want and lean back. You need to include what you tried and didn't work or at least what approaches you did consider. Without you only earn down votings

Comment: The inherit flaw of any approach will be the need to keep the page open. You might be better off with a classic agent since you don't speak Java

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach it is:
Identify the date/time you want to check on.
Write a function in SSJS/Java to work out the difference between that date/time and now. 
Write a function in SJSS/Java to use that time difference and return an output.
Use CSS or Javascript based on the result of the second function to style the document or give an alert.

Comment: Thanks, but i thought i can use  ccs javascript only without SJSS/Java , i dontknow java. I 'm not sure where to start

Comment: You don't have to use Java. You can use SSJS instead to compute a property like style or styleClass, to give you the CSS styling.

Comment: I used Paul's approach. As long as you reload the page often enough it works. I actually would use more than one color. Eg orange when half the time is over